# Items are being replaced by another in the Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

When I add the first item in the DataGridView it's OK but when I add the second one it replaces the last item added.

```
Private Sub add()

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        'DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
        DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.RowCount - 1).Cells("TransID").Value = txttrans.Text
        DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.RowCount - 1).Cells("ProductCode").Value = txtprodcode.Text
        DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.RowCount - 1).Cells("ProductName").Value = cmbprodname.Text
        DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.RowCount - 1).Cells("Quantity").Value = txtqty.Text
        DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.RowCount - 1).Cells("Price").Value = txtprc.Text
        DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.RowCount - 1).Cells("Amount").Value = txtat.Text
        DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.RowCount - 1).Cells("CustomerName").Value = txtcust.Text
        DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.RowCount - 1).Cells("Date1").Value = txtdate.Text
       
    Next i

  
End Sub
```

And this is in my ADDbutton:

```
Private Sub btnadd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnadd.Click
    
    Try
        add()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Dim total As Integer

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

        total += row.Cells("Amount").Value

    Next

    txtamt.Text = total
```

Comment: Based on the error message you are getting you are getting a data structure error message. I just went into visual studio and tried to recreate this scenario based on your input. I ran into the issue that if I have a datagridview and I wanted to create a row based on the structure of the datagridview it was next to impossible. My recommendation is to create a datatable with the columns you desire

Answer (score 0):

Should this (and the other lines)

```
DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.RowCount - 1).Cells("TransID").Value = txttrans.Text
```

not be

```
DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("TransID").Value = txttrans.Text
```

because otherwise you are just addint the row `DataGridView1.RowCount - 1`.

Comment: It worked but when i add the third item it replaces all the last 2 items

Comment: i Dont have yet an update code for that form. I'm working on a Point of Sale. and after populating the textbox i wll add it to the datagridview

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Create a datatable with with the data structue that you need. I provided a small example of what to do. The data column array contains the column information. dt.columns.addRange sets your columns to the desired column name structure. The dt.newRow() method returns an empty row but contains the necessary schema so that you won't get the error that you are getting. Once you have added all the rows necessary you can reference the rows in the datatable using row["columnName"]

Use datagridview.datasource = dt to bind the datagrid to the datatable object.

```
  public Form1()
    {
        DataColumn column0 = new DataColumn("TransID");
        DataColumn column1 = new DataColumn("Price");
        DataColumn column2 = new DataColumn("Quantity");

        columns[0] = column0;
        columns[1] = column1;
        columns[2] = column2;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(columns);

        //Creates a datarow object based on the dataable's schema
        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();

        row["TransID"] = "Transaction Text";
        row["Price"] = "Price Text";
        row["Quantity"] = "Quantity";

        //Add the row to the dataTable
        dt.Rows.Add(row);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

Comment: I am trying to add items.
..There's an error appear said"Column named TransID cannot be found.Parameter name:columnName.
but when i checked it its the same name.

Comment: Sounds like there is some schema issue. Can you post the complete datagridview declaration? By schema I mean the layout of the datagridview's data structure. I ran into this issue last week myself.

Comment: Also, did you declare your columns through the designer or did you declare them programatically?

Comment: Me.TransID = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        Me.ProductCode = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        Me.ProductName = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        Me.Quantity = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Me.Price = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        Me.Amount = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        Me.CustomerName = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        Me.Date1 = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

Comment: also this one...'DataGridView1
        '
        Me.DataGridView1.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control
        Me.DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize
        Me.DataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn() {Me.TransID, Me.ProductCode, Me.ProductName, Me.Quantity, Me.Price, Me.Amount, Me.CustomerName, Me.Date1})
        Me.DataGridView1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(9, 58)
        Me.DataGridView1.Name = "DataGridView1"
        Me.DataGridView1.ReadOnly = True

Comment: @gsirianni i delared it in the designer. in the arrow of the  datagridview